# how to input many times in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a simple program in python that goes as so:

```
print "enter 100 words:"
1 = raw_input("word 1")
2 = raw_input("word 2")
```

I do not want to type `raw_input` 100 times.
please give a solution.

Comment: Also, 1 and 2 are not valid names for variables.

Comment: I'd suggest you read the [tutorial chapter about control flow](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print "Enter 100 words:"
words = [] # create a list
for x in range(100): # loop through all the numbers from 0 to 100
  words.append(raw_input("Word {}".format(x + 1))) # ask for the word,
                                                   # then add it to the list
```

This will simply create a list, then add to it 100 times.

Comment: You can also simply do `range(100)`. But nice solution; +1 :).

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner :

```
Inputs = map (raw_input, map (lambda x: "Word " + str(x) + " : ", xrange (1, 5)))

print Inputs
```

Sample Run:

```
$ python Test.py
Word 1 : A
Word 2 : B
Word 3 : C
Word 4 : D
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: You should go see [the code golf site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) `:)`

Comment: Learning python now. So just tried that. Thanks for the codegolf site :)